# Exporting Earth Engine Data in lat, lng, band value format to CSV

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Is there a way I can export the data from code below into a CSV file to my drive in format of X, Y, WindSpeed? Where X and Y are coordinate of a point in that bounding box.

```
                              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-01-01', '2022-01-02'))
                              .select('u_component_of_wind_10m')ERA5_Land Hourly
                              
var ERA5List = ERA5Collection.toList(ERA5Collection.size())
var ERA5 = ee.Image(ERA5List.get(0))
var bbox2 = region.bounds()
var bbox = ERA5.clip(bbox2)

var visParams = {
  min: -40.0,
  max: 35.0,
  palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

var clipERA5 = ERA5.clip(region);
Map.addLayer(clipERA5, visParams, "Wind");
Map.centerObject(clipERA5, 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` to sample each pixel inside a polygon from an image. You then just need to export that data as a table. Since, you did not provide a polygon I am not sure if there are ERA images available for your roi; however, you can add a `print` before converting the collection to a list, so you are sure that there are images available in that spatiotemporal window.

```
var resul = ERA5.sample({
  region: region, 
  scale: 27830, // Native resolution of the image
  projection: 'EPSG:4326', // Set a CRS code
  geometries: true // So lat long coordinates are returned
});

Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(resul),
    description: 'ERA5_sample'
  });
```

Comment: How do I do this for entire ImageCollection like export one CSV for each hour for specific time frame or do I have to use a loop and iterate inside var ERA5 = ee.Image(ERA5List.get(i))?

Comment: You can map over a list of the dates in your collection to obtain a single image by date. This can be done by filtering the images according to the date and the reducing them using `mean`, `median`, etc. Then, you can use `toBands` to convert the image collection to a multiband image, and finally, use `sample` to sample the pixels.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I couldn't explain what I want to achieve in 2nd part. I want to get one CSV for each hour, So 24 CSV's for 24 hours. Taking mean will produce a single CSV of daily average. But I want individual CSV's for each hour. How do I accomplish this? Also I am a beginner to EE, it would be nice if you edited your answer on ```toBands``` part.

Comment: It would be the same process but instead of reducing by date, you can reduce by date and hour. I suggest that you include all these details in your question and a reproducible example so anyone can try to solve your issue. Also, this way your question and answers will be more useful for future users.